# Source for "Hamakom" said at shiva and variations

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, mourning-aveilus, sitting-shiva

What is the source for the text of hamakom?

In Israel I noticed that they add some words that I never heard in the States (something like"vlo yosifo lidavek?od") , what is the source for them and why dont we say them in the states?

Comment: regarding the appended phrase https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14270/759

Answer (score 5):

The Talmud in Sanhedrin 19A says about the Kohen Gadol:

> כשהוא מתנחם כו': איבעיא להו כי מנחם הוא אחריני היכי אמר להו ת''ש והוא אומר תתנחמו היכי דמי אילימא כי מנחמי אחריני לדידיה אמר להו איהו תתנחמו נחשא קא רמי להו אלא כי מנחם לאחריני אמר להו תתנחמו ש''מ

The translation is:

> WHEN HE IS COMFORTED BY OTHERS etc. The schoolmen asked: When he consoled others, what did he say to them? - Come and hear! 'And he said [to them], Be comforted'. On what occasion [did he actually say this]? Shall we say, when others comforted him? But how could he say, 'Be comforted'? He would suggest ill-omen to them! - it must therefore be taken that when he comforted others, he said: 'Be comforted'. Draw your own conclusion! (Soncino)

The Rambam says in Sefer Shoftim, Hilchoth Evel, chapter 13, Halacha 2,

> וְאוֹמְרִים לָהֶן תְּנֻחֲמוּ מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם
> Be consoled by Heaven

The statement in the Gemara seems to be the same/similar using: "....תתנחם/תתנחמו/תנוחמו"

The Shulchan Aruch follows the same terminology (many details differ but there is no "Hamokom").

We find that the statement of "Hamakom" is mentionned, but with the word "יי" instead of "Hamakom" in [Prisha YD 393, 3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6573)

In Wikipedia I found that the source of the usited statement is in Shevut Yaakov from Rabbi Yaacov Reisher, tome 3, siman 98:

> יש שכתבו שכפי הנראה המקור לנוסח זה הוא בספר שבות יעקב של רבי יעקב ריישר:‏
>
> גם באתי להודיע חידוש בדין, דאם אותן המתאבלים עמהם מנחמים את אבילם, יאמרו נוסח זה בזה הלשון: המקום ינחם אתכם ואותנו עם שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים‏
>
> — שבות יעקב חלק ג סימן צח

This [link](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/print.asp?id=51405&kod=&modul=15&codeClient=58) seems interesting about this topic.

It seems that there is no essential difference between the diverse expressions. It seems  that the recitation is not the essential part but rather the Nichum is. I am convinced that the changing details in Nussach and the relative lack of real interest for this in Poskim is an illustration of this. After all there is diverse possibility that express the same idea.

Comment: The Prisha does not say Hamakom. He uses two phrase, השוכן בבית זה ינחמך and ה' ינחמך עם שאר אבילי ציון.

Comment: Thanks @Eliyahu. I will fix it later

Comment: @Elyahu see edit

Answer (score 0):

I found a not too recent source which actually has the Nussach straight:

גשר החיים פרק טז ז:ב - ומנחמין אותו בברכה המסורתית המקום ינחם אותך (ואם האבלים רבים אומרים "אתכם") בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים.

He does say אותך for singular. See [Proper recitation of Hamakom Yenachem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17046/proper-recitation-of-hamakom-yenachem) for more details.